# Teradata formatting amounts of money

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I have a problem with formatting, I exports data of the amount of money balances to excel, but I have a bad format.

```
SELECT COALESCE(TRIM(CAST(ZEROIFNULL(balance) AS DECIMAL(15,2) FORMAT '--Z(15)D9(2)')), 0);
```

I would like to change the character dot on the comma and when the balance is equal to 0 to display 0,00 because now I have a .00

Is it possible without changes to VARCHAR ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier when you switch to `TO_CHAR` instead of a `FORMAT`:

```
to_char(coalesce(balance,0),'999999999999990,99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')
```

Comment: Super. This is what I meant.
it is possible to set for the whole session 
in Oracle SQL: 
`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=",."`
how to do it in TERADATA: 
`.SET` ??

Comment: @MartinusP: No, NLS-parameters don't exist in Teradata.